# Sending an email via gmail using delphi 7

Tags: email, delphi, smtp, gmail, delphi-7

I am trying to set up an automated email for a database backup agent that is written in delphi 7.
I need to send the email via a web based email system as the local SMTP cannot be used.
The code i am using is returning Socket Error # 10060.

Here is the code.

```
begin
IdSMTP1    := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
try
  IdMessage1.From.Address := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Subject      := Memo2.Lines.Text;
  IdMessage1.Body.Text    := Memo3.Lines.Text;
  try
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode   := sslmUnassigned;

    IdSMTP1.Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP1.Port      := 587;
    IdSMTP1.Username  := 'xxx@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP1.Password  := 'xxx';
    IdSMTP1.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    IdSMTP1.Connect();
    IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  Finally
    IdSMTP1.Free;
  end;
finally
  IdMessage1.Free;
end;
end;
```

Comment: there is no mail clients on the same computer as it is just a database server with some running processes

Comment: Check this article for some additional Indy configuration ideas: https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/send-secured-smtp-email-from-delphi-applications/

Comment: It wont run from the machine i am developing it on, through the delphi 7 IDE. It will be the same network as the server though.

Comment: Are you using the current Indy version?

Comment: I don't think so but the new version states it is not complete and the version of delphi i am running is very old, i will give it a go.

Comment: You did see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2145515/62576?

Comment: "*the new version states it is not complete*" - I assume you are referring to the fact that it is marked as "Work in progress", right? Indy 10 is still the active version that you should be using. "*the version of delphi i am running is very old*" - Indy supports Delphi versions all the way back to v5.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to send the email via a web based email system as the local SMTP cannot be used.

You cannot use `TIdSMTP` to send web-based email.  You have to use `TIdHTTP` instead and simulate all of the steps that a user would have to go through in a web browser (download and submit a login webform, then request, populate, and submit the webpage that provides the user with the outgoing email form, etc).  That is a lot of work.

If the user has an SMTP server, you can use `TIdSMTP` for that.  But, even if the *user* does not have their own SMTP server, the user's *ISP* has an SMTP server.  If connecting to the SMTP server of the *user's ISP* is not an option, you can try using `TIdSMTPRelay` (Indy 10+) to send emails directly to the SMTP servers of the email *recipients* instead (since everyone's ISP has an SMTP server for *receiving* emails).  The catch is that you have to provide the host/IP of a DNS server in the `TIdSMTPRelay.DNSServer` property, but you can enumerate the user's local network adapters to discover their DNS servers and use one of them, or use one of the many public DNS servers online.

> The code i am using is returning Socket Error # 10060

Gmail's port 587 requires the SMTP `STARTTLS` command, which `TIdSMTP` in Indy 9 did not support.  You need Indy 10 for that.  For Indy 9, you can use Gmail's port 465 instead.  Just be sure to set the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.PassThrough` property to False before calling `TIdSMTP.Connect()`.

You are also leaking the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` object.

```
IdSMTP1 := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
try
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(IdSMTP1);
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode   := sslmUnassigned;
  SSLHandler.PassThrough       := False;

  IdMessage1 := TIdMessage.Create(IdSMTP1);
  IdMessage1.From.Address := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Subject      := Memo2.Lines.Text;
  IdMessage1.Body.Text    := Memo3.Lines.Text;

  IdSMTP1.Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Port      := 465;
  IdSMTP1.Username  := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Password  := 'xxx';
  IdSMTP1.IOHandler := SSLHandler;

  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  try
    IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
  finally
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
finally
  IdSMTP1.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Does Google still allow access to smtp.gmail.com without switching your account "Allow less secure apps access" to ON ?? I thought they implemented a stricter policy where you need to set that option to ON before being able to use smtp.gmail.com. You can set it at http://myaccount.google.com/security (all the way at the bottom of that page) or at http://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps directly. (Don't forget to set it back if it doesn't help)

Comment: If you enable 2-step verification in your Google account, the "less secure apps" feature is disabled. You can then create application-specific passwords to allow apps that do not support 2-step to login to Google/Gmail. It works fine with `TIdSMTP`.

Comment: Good to know. It wasn't clear if Jonny has the 2-steps login enabled. So the choices are enabling 2-step and [using a specific app password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) or [setting "Allow less secure apps access" to ON](http://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: Basically, yes.  Indy does not implement OAuth protocols yet, so it cannot login using Gmail's 2-step SASL authentication (though there are some third-party implementations floating around, or you can write your own).